# Callback and Functions with jquery

Tags: jquery, function, callback

I have already asked a question but I wanted to ask it in another way with another question. Is that possible call a method 10 times in asynchronous mode without specifying a return value. I am doing everything in a single page. I do not need to visit any other page. I have got a set of operation, each operation should wait for the previous one.

like this:

```
$.get('myhtmlpage.html', function(){
    myCallBack(param1, param2);
});
```

or like this:

```
function translate(i) {
    google.language.translate(testua, languages[i], languages[i+1], function(result) {
        if (result.translation) {
            text = result.translation;
            f.textarea1.value = text;
            if (i < translationNumber) { translate(i++); }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe these are telling me something but I need to see a sample..

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Callback_and_Functions

or suggest me sth please.

A sample code would be great!

thanks..
regards..

Comment: have you specified "myCallBack"? I'm not sure i understand. What do you get back when you hit myhtmlpage.html via $.get?

Comment: Its not completely clear what youre trying to do here. Is `translate` supposed to be your call back, or is it something thats called from within `myCallback`? How do you need to call it multiple times - is it `translate` you need to call `n` times, or `$.get`?

Comment: I just need a piece of sample code that tells me how to call a function asynchronously guys. The codes in the question are the sample codes, not my own code. Put it this way: you are looping from 1 to 10. 2 will wait for 1 , 3 will wait for 2 and so forth. However, in my code, each process running takes much longer. Each one should wait for each other. Is it clear now? BTW: Thanks so much for replying.Ozlem.

Comment: I think what you would want is an observer pattern. This would set your code up so that when one event happens you can execute the next. 

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13914/Observer-Design-Pattern-Using-JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misunderstanding how JavaScript works. In JavaScript you only have one thread, which means that you can't call any functions asynchronously *execpt* when you do AJAX-style calls.

The short answer is, you can't call methods asynchronously.

Comment: maybe my explanation is wrong. I just need to call a function for each element of an array and I want them to wait for each other.for example, you have got an array which count from 1 to 10. 2 will wait for 1 , 3 will wait for 2 and so forth. However, the cost of each process (each element of my array) is much more costly in terms of time, a few seconds for each maybe more.That's why I need this. Now can you help me over this explanation?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is still that Javascript can't do it. You could do:
    function_1();
    function_2();
    function_3();

But you can't make JavaScript run them in parallel within a browser. The only exception is if `function_1()` or `function_2()` makes an AJAX call.